# Handling White-spaces in free-marker template

Tags: xml, freemarker, smooks

I just want to remove white-spaces in XML tags using a free-marker template

I written condition in free-marker that null line is excluded when input tag is null

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample relevant code and current/ expected results

Comment: <#if (.vars["item"].Marks[0]!"") !=""><mark>${.vars["item"].Marks}</mark><else><#rt></#if> ,in this code,written a condition such that if input is not null print the value otherwise remove the whitespace when input tag is empty..BUT ELSE CONDITION IS NOT WORKING AS IT PRODUCING WHITE_SPACE WHEN INPUT IS EMPTY..Please Suggest me the solution

Comment: You are checking `.vars["item"].Marks[0]` and printing different object `.vars["item"].Marks`

Comment: Just for sample i have mentioned,Marks is the field to be printed.That field is actually printed,else condition trimming is not working